# Having issues parsing String to integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to show the total sales for each salesperson for the week using a multi-line String named `sales` as input data. I have been able to successfully return a dictionary named `dic`, however the sales numbers remain as Strings, and I can't total them up for each salesperson as when I parse them with the `int()` method like so, `int(i.split(";")[-1])`, it throws an error.

Also as a side note, does anyone know why I can't get the day of the week from the input with `(i.split(";")[1])`? Thanks!

Current output:

```
{'': '', 'Lauren': '91', 'Tim': '83'}
```

Desired output

```
{'Lauren': 10, 'Tim': 11}
```

My current code:

```
sales = '''
Lauren;Tuesday;9
Tim;Wednesday;8
Tim;Thursday;3
Lauren;Friday;1
'''

def salesCalc(sales):
    dic = {}
    for i in sales.splitlines():
        if i.split(";")[0] in dic:
            dic[i.split(";")[0]] += i.split(";")[-1]   
        else:
            dic[i.split(";")[0]] = i.split(";")[-1]
    return dic

print(salesCalc(sales))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are very close, and you have a typo in your example :-)

```py
sales = '''
Lauren;Tuesday;9
Tim;Wednesday;8
Tim;Thursday;3
Lauren;Friday;1
'''

def salesCalc(sales):
    dic = {}
    for line in sales.splitlines():
        attrs = line.split(";")
     
        if len(attrs) > 1: # this is to make sure that we only consider line with data because we can get '' as line
            # this is just short-cut, it can be also written as
            # if attrs[0] in dic:
            #     dic[attrs[0]] = dic[attrs[0]] + int(attrs[-1])
            # else:
            #     dic[attrs[0]] = int(attrs[-1])
            dic[attrs[0]] = dic[attrs[0]] + int(attrs[-1]) if attrs[0] in dic else int(attrs[-1])
    return dic

print(salesCalc(sales))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, as well as for pointing out the typo! Could you explain how you handled the first blank line with `dic[attrs[0]] = dic[attrs[0]] + int(attrs[-1]) if attrs[0] in dic else int(attrs[-1])` ?

Comment: it is handled by `if len(attrs) > 1:`

Comment: What I meant was can you explain what is the thought process behind the logic of `if len(attrs) > 1:
            dic[attrs[0]] = dic[attrs[0]] + int(attrs[-1]) if attrs[0] in dic else int(attrs[-1])` ? Thanks!

Comment: sorry, I have added comments to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You had two problems with your current script.  First, the sample `sales` input should begin with data on the very first line.  The version you had began with a blank line, which was causing your loop to pick up on empty string as the first key/value.  Second, you need to wrap the `RHS` of the dictionary with `int()`, to work with actual numbers.  As you had it before, you were doing string concatenation.  Putting both of these together:

```
sales = '''Lauren;Tuesday;9
Tim;Wednesday;8
Tim;Thursday;3
Laurent;Friday;1
'''

def salesCalc(sales):
    dic = {}
    for i in sales.splitlines():
        if i.split(";")[0] in dic:
            dic[i.split(";")[0]] += int(i.split(";")[-1])
        else:
            dic[i.split(";")[0]] = int(i.split(";")[-1])
    return dic

print(salesCalc(sales))  # {'Tim': 11, 'Lauren': 9, 'Laurent': 1}
```

Answer (score -1):

First: you don't need to split row every time you try get element.
Second: to convert string to int use `int`

```py
def salesCalc(sales):
    dic = {}
    for i in sales.splitlines():
        splitted = i.split(";")
        if splitted[0]:
            if splitted[0] in dic:
                dic[splitted[0]] += int(splitted[-1])
            else:
                dic[splitted[0]] = int(splitted[-1])
    return dic
```

Comment: Your code above does not work. int() does not work as it throws an error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
    dic[splitted[0]] = int(splitted[-1])
Line 25 in salesCalc (Solution.py)
    print(salesCalc(sales))
Line 28 in <module> (Solution.py)`